# Poubelle ou ordures?

Tags: vocabulaire

je veux savoir si 'poubelle' peut être utilisé pour dire 'garbage' comme le mot 'ordures', ou si c'est exclusivement pour une chose dans laquelle on met les ordures.

In other words, is 'poubelle' just garbage can, or can it also be garbage?

Would I be correct to say: Il faut jeter les poubelles. You have to throw away the garbage.

Translators online prefer: Il faut jeter les ordures
But in school I always used poubelles here and it just felt more natural. Can somebody give further info?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

*Poubelle* would normally be for the container. *Jeter les poubelles* would mean to empty the trash. *Jeter quelque chose à la poubelle* means to throw something in the trash.

The *ordures* are what you put in the *poubelle(s)*. One *jette les ordures à la poubelle*, but then one *vide la/les poubelle(s)* to empty the trash.

Answer (score 2):

L'usage de "poubelles" par métonymie pour désigner leur contenu (et donc les ordures) est possible. On parle par exemple de camion-poubelle pour le véhicule qui s'occupe du ramassage des ordures, ou on peut dire "les poubelles s'entassent" alors qu'en réalité ne s'entassent que des sacs-poubelles (pleins d'ordures).

Cependant les deux mots ne sont pas synonymes pour autant. Si vous constatez que vos poubelles sont pleines l'usage veut plutôt que vous disiez "il faut vider les poubelles".

Comment: Pas sûr que *camion-poubelle* soit vraiment une métonymie. On peut considérer un camion-poubelle comme une grande poubelle dans laquelle sont vidées les poubelles placées le long des rues, poubelles qui elles-mêmes ont reçu le contenu de plus petites poubelles. De même, les *sacs poubelle* sont des sacs, des "poubelles souples", pas des ordures.